# Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'. Error while trying to add an ID attribute to a button JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, replace, getelementsbyclassname, google-chrome-console

So, I wanted to execute some JavaScript into my Android app that is in Java, but when testing the JavaScript that has to run; in the Chrome Console (`Ctrl-Shift-J`), I get the following error:

> Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature:
> 'interest-cohort'.

The site is chess.com, and the error occurs when I run the following code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(`<button type="button" class="ui_v5-button-component ui_v5-button-primary ui_v5-button-large ui_v5-button-full">
Play
</button>`, `<button type="button" id="jhghjikjhgbjinb" class="ui_v5-button-component ui_v5-button-primary ui_v5-button-large ui_v5-button-full">
Play
</button>`);
```

What I'm trying to do is access the "Play" button on [this site](https://www.chess.com/play/online) and click it. Is there any other way to do the same? I tried using `document.getElementsByClassName()`, but how can I change the website's content?

Answer (score 1):

`interest-cohort` permissions policy enables a site to declare that it does not want to be included in the user's list of sites for cohort calculation
https://web.dev/floc/.

You can check if any content security policies (CSP) are enabled in the site.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. I checked but couldn't find if it is enabled or not, I guess it is though. If yes, how can I bypass or disable it or change the website's content?

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/70915754/4205374

Comment: @hdoitc, I don't own chess.com. It's apparently a company. How can I change the website's content? I don't have *direct* access to the website's code. How can I use JavaScript to get the elements? Or just bypass the error/exception/whatever it is so that I can continue changing the website's code?