# how to exclude my site from Google's interest-cohort policy?

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers

today I have some new warnings in chrome console:

`Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.`
`Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ch-ua-full-version-list'.`

I don't want my site to be included inside this google's feature

searching the web I found the following solution (`.htaccess file`):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header always set Permissions-Policy: interest-cohort=()
</IfModule>
```

but it doesn't help. The warnings are still in console

Is there an efficient way to stop appearing this messages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google have stopped running the experiment and are looking at a new approach: https://blog.google/products/chrome/get-know-new-topics-api-privacy-sandbox/amp/

So you don’t need to exclude you site from it anymore (hence the error message).

Note also even when they were running that experiment, it only generated and used an error interest cohort when using Google Ads. So again I need to do anything if not running ads. And if that interested in privacy then probably not running any ads that would use this.